# Combine sqlite database files (multiple tables per file) into one file

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in python and I have multiple database files which I now want to combine into one big file. Each database is associated with a specific topic but they all share the same structure. I'll be querying them separately -- I just want to combine them into one file so that it's easier to move them around.

One dirty way I can think of goes like this:

```
create_string = 'CREATE TABLE %s_table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, doca INTEGER, docb INTEGER)' %topic1 
cur.execute(create_string)
```

This way, I'll have the topic name prefixed with each table and when I do a query, I'll have to construct a query string with the appropriate topic name. But there should be a better way to solve this. Am I missing something obvious?

[How to Merge Multiple Database files in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913369/how-to-merge-multiple-database-files-in-sqlite)

[How can I merge many SQLite databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80801/how-can-i-merge-many-sqlite-databases)

I've already looked at these and it seems my problem is easier to solve than theirs, but I still can't find a better solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd use a tool like [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link but I need to do this from a script.

Comment: You're going to be doing it repeatedly??

Comment: Well, you can always write a SQLite script to do it.  But you'd probably have to dump and reload the tables.

Comment: yes. I need to do the whole process once every week (most probably)

Comment: @HotLicks Is there a way to partition the database file while creating tables, based on my topics? (is partition the right word for a thing like this??) I would prefer the tables to be divided at creation time itself. That said, sqlite script should work too. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move whole tables (as in, not merge them but bring in tables from a different file), you can do so in unix like so:

```
 sqlite3 'from_this_db.db' '.dump' | sqlite3 -batch 'to_this_db.db'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're solution is OK. Note that you can give the "source" cursor as input to the "destination" cursor *executemany* method. Something like:

```
src.execute('SELECT * FROM ...')
dest.executemany('INSERT INTO ...', src)
```